# Passbook is not opening in Safari

Tags: passbook, wallet

I'm currently developing backend for pass generation. I have created sample pass using all guidelines but it doesn't open up on Iphone. Is there any way to debug a problem, cause right now Safari is just showing message - "Safari could not download file".

Here is a link with sample pass:
"https://distributor-test.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/pass"

Thanks for any advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the errors logged in the console, you have more than one field with an ID of "front-primary". Each field must have a unique ID. Fix the names of the field and try again.

If you have a Mac, you can open the output from an iPhone using XCode or the syslog. This helps pinpoint issues with passes.